# How can i get html5 video duration on page load with angular 4?

Tags: html, angular, html5-video

*html*

```
<video #v >
    <source src="{{video.videoUrl}}" type="video/mp4" />
 </video>

<button (click)="getDuration(v)">
  Get Duration 
</button>

<input type="range" step="0.1"  min="0" 
   max="getDuration(v)">
```

*.ts*

```
video = {
   videoUrl :"myvideo.mp4"
   length: null,
}

getDuration(v){
  let dur = v.duration;
  dur = dur.toFixed();

  this.video.length = dur;
  return dur;
}
```

I can get video url on button click but i can't get on page load.

**How can i get video duration when page loads video?**

**Plus:** I tried to call `getDuration(v)` function in `ngOnInit()` but get error, because `getDuration(v)` has parameter.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You need to wait until the element is loaded. Use the [ngAfterViewInit()](https://angular.io/api/core/AfterViewInit) lifecycle hook instead `ngOnInit()`.
2. Use the [@ViewChild](https://angular.io/api/core/AfterViewInit) decorator to use the element reference from the template in your typescript logic.

Using ViewChild in your case:

```
@ViewChild('v') v;

ngAfterViewInit() {
console.log(this.v);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But i don't understand how to use ViewChild thing? Can you understand bit more detail about how to use it?

Comment: It worked with **ElementRef** by the way. Just wanted to say.   
`@ViewChild('v') v:ElementRef;`  `this.getDuration(this.v.nativeElement)`